# Preserving first position capitalization after modifying a string

Tags: python, string

I am writing a program that changes input words into pig latin. My code works and everything is as it should be except for capitalization. I want to make the first position i.e. words[0] capital if the inputted word started with a capital letted. I have tried a number of ways but cant seem to figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

```
word=input("Enter the word: ")

word=word.lower()

if word.isalpha():
  if word[0:len(word)] not in ' ':
    if word[0] in 'aeiou':
      word=word + 'yay'
      print(word)
    elif word[0:1] in 'qu':
      word=word[2:]+word[0]+word[1] +'ay'
      print(word)
    elif word[0] not in 'aeiou':
      while(word[0] not in 'aeiou'):
        word=word[1:]+word[0:1]
      word=word+'ay'
      print(word)

  else:
    print("Invalid Word")
else:
  print("Invalid Word")
```

Comment: word = word.title()

Comment: I know that thats the command to do so but im asking how would i fit it in here without have to write it 4 different times?

Comment: Please, provide sample `input` and `output` to better understand

Comment: why would you have to write it 4 different times?

Comment: So if i were to input Strip, the expected output should be Ipstray (since it is running through the last elif and adding ay

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

capitalize = False

word=input("Enter the word: ")

if word[0] in 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ':
    capitalize = True

word = word.lower()

if word.isalpha():
  if word[0:len(word)] not in ' ':
    if word[0] in 'aeiou':
      word=word + 'yay'
    elif word[0:1] in 'qu':
      word=word[2:]+word[0]+word[1] +'ay'
    elif word[0] not in 'aeiou':
      while(word[0] not in 'aeiou'):
        word=word[1:]+word[0:1]
      word=word+'ay'
  else:
    print("Invalid Word")
else:
  print("Invalid Word")

if capitalize is True:
    word = word.title()

print(word)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way :

```
word=input("Enter the word: ")

if word[0].isupper() and word.isalpha():
    word=word.lower()
    if word[0:len(word)] not in ' ':
      if word[0] in 'aeiou':
        word=word + 'yay'
        print(word[0].upper() + word[1:])
      elif word[0:1] in 'qu':
        word=word[2:]+word[0]+word[1] +'ay'
        print(word[0].upper() + word[1:])
      elif word[0] not in 'aeiou':
        while(word[0] not in 'aeiou'):
          word=word[1:]+word[0:1]
        word=word+'ay'
        print(word[0].upper() + word[1:])
    else:
      print("Invalid Word")

elif word[0].islower() and word.isalpha():
    word=word.lower()
    if word[0:len(word)] not in ' ':
      if word[0] in 'aeiou':
        word=word + 'yay'
        print(word)
      elif word[0:1] in 'qu':
        word=word[2:]+word[0]+word[1] +'ay'
        print(word)
      elif word[0] not in 'aeiou':
        while(word[0] not in 'aeiou'):
          word=word[1:]+word[0:1]
        word=word+'ay'
        print(word)
    else:
      print("Invalid Word")

else:
  print("Invalid Word")
```

To better understand compile [above](https://repl.it/MOsp) code here.